# set active profile without spring

Tags: java, properties, configuration, jvm, properties-file

Our web app need to run on two different servers. There are also two different properties files for those servers, like application.prd1.properties and application.prd1.properties. I do not use spring boot. So I can not use **-Dspring.profiles.active=prd1** script.

Now I am getting the properties file like below image
[image]

How can I use two different properties files on two different servers without spring boot?

Comment: You gotta let your code know which property to load based on some variable. How are you loading the properties now? How's the application packaged?

Comment: @Leonardo Emmanuel de Azevedo I have just added my way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have defined local variable for different servers like **-DENV=prd1** and **-DENV=prd2**

```
public static void init(String server) {
  String env = System.getProperty("ENV")
  ResourceBundle res = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application." + env );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a jar jar file with your application.
Given that, you can create a script to run it based on the server.

In the entry point of the application you can parse the arguments:

```
public static void Main(String[] args){
    if (args.length == 1)
        System.exit(1);

    String server = args[1];
    init(server);
}
```

Then, the init will be a little bit different:

```
static void init(String server) {
ResourceBundle resourceBundle;
switch (server){
    case "server1":
        resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application.server1.properties");
        break;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Be aware that the above code does not compile.